# Relabeling of filesystems (SELinux) fails

Tags: mdadm, gentoo, selinux, security, ext4

After compiling the policy modules and re-compiling my core packages (Gentoo 32bit) I wanted to relabel the filesystems (via `rlpkg -a -r`) and packages but I get these error messages:

> Relabeling filesystem types: btrfs ext2 ext3 ext4 jfs xfs
>   /usr/sbin/setfiles set context /->system_u:object_r:root_t failed:'Operation not supported'
>
> /usr/sbin/setfiles set context /boot->system_u:object_r:boot_t failed:'Operation not supported'
>
> /usr/sbin/setfiles set context /home->system_u:object_r:home_root_t failed:'Operation not supported'
>
> /usr/sbin/setfiles set context /srv->system_u:object_r:var_t failed:'Operation not supported'
>
> /usr/sbin/setfiles set context /tmp->system_u:object_r:tmp_t failed:'Operation not supported'
>   /usr/sbin/setfiles set context /usr->system_u:object_r:usr_t failed:'Operation not supported'
>
> /usr/sbin/setfiles set context /var->system_u:object_r:var_t failed:'Operation not supported'
>
> Scanning for shared libraries with text relocations...
>
> 0 libraries with text relocations, 0 not relabeled.
>   Scanning for PIE binaries with text relocations...
>
> 0 binaries with text relocations detected.

/boot, /home, /srv, /tmp, /usr and /var are on /dev/md1-7 which are formatted using ext4.

I have found old bugreports on similiar issues but no solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have support enabled for extended attributes on the filesystem. You may need to enable it in the kernel or mount with the 'xattr' option. On redhat systems it doesnt seem you need to explicitly set this flag, nevertheless gentoo might differ here.

Comment: extended attributes for ext4 is enabled, security labels, too. Other suggestions?

Comment: Can you try to run the following command on /var?
"attr -s test -V test /var && attr -r test /var" it should be successful.

Comment: Yes, it is. `Attribute "test" set to a 4 byte value for /var:
test`

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I did a fresh gentoo installation, same configuration.

However, udev seems to have problems, as `/dev/console` and the `/dev/tty[1-2]` aren't loaded:

> /etc/init.d/sshd[1205]: ERROR: sshd failed to start
>
> /etc/init.d/urandom[1219]: ERROR: urandom failed to start
>
> init: open(/dev/console): No such file or directory
>
> init: open(/dev/console): No such file or directory
>
> agetty[1233]: /dev/tty2: not a character device
>
> agetty[1232]: /dev/tty1: not a character device

Comment: Turns out that that the udev fstab entry was the problem: `udev           /dev            tmpfs           rw,rootcontext=system_u:object_r:device_t,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=10m,mode=755    0 0`
However, SELinux is disabled.